# itextpdf xmlworker PdfPageEventHelper.onGenericTag usage

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I am using below dependency for html to pdf

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Need to use a custom/generic tags, for that I need to define a chunk and then a generic tag, that is doable using iText but needs to be done through html.

Can anyone please help me out with when onGenericTag method will get called, like onParagraph is called when a p tag is encontered.

Comment: That would require introducing either a special (possible non-)HTML tag or a special CSS attribute, and then overriding XML Worker's behavior to deal with that special tag or attribute. Since support for XML Worker is expiring in favor of iText 7 + pdfHTML, you'll need to find someone who's knowledgeable enough about XML, but who isn't bound by the "we no longer support iText 5" policy.